# Why is EjsGrid not rendering on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, blazor, ejs

We have Blazor app, using EjsGrid.
It is working well on localhost, but it fails on the server (IIS).
The problem is in rendering the Grid. On server it fails with error "rendering component: A member with the name "" already exists".

We have tried to reinstall .NET (v6, v7 and v8 as well), but the problem remains.

What can be wrong?

[image: Error message in client browser]

[image: Source code of DTO viewed in the Grid]

[image: EjsGrid source code]

[image: Code loading data]

[image: Working solution on localhost]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This error may be caused by scripts are not served on the login page because you are not authenticated, you can try to change the authentication type in the web.config or add a web.config in the directory containing scripts, which specifies authorization rules.